# Add event handler to DOM element that is created after a $resource get (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having a hard time enabling a Bootstrap's popover component to my dom elements.

I'm working with AngularJS and on my template, I am using the ng-repeat directive to create a gallery.

```
<div ng-repeat="phone in phones" >
    <a class="thumb" href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">
        <img class="img-responsive phone_image" ng-src="{{phone.image_path}}" data-content="{{phone.text}}" rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover">
    </a>
</div>
```

On my template controller, I'm fetching the phones data from a third party API and than injecting it to the scopes variable "phones", like so:

```
phoneControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Phones',
    function ($scope, Cards) {
        // Phones is the service that queries the phone data to the API
        Phones.query(function(data){
            // Got a response, add received to the phones variable
            $scope.phones = data;
            // for each .card_image element,give it the popover property
            $('.phone_image').popover({
                'trigger': 'hover'
            });
        });
    }]
);
```

My problem lies with the `$('.phone_image').popover` segment. My thought was that by doing it inside the query's callback function it would work, since that's when the ".phone_image" elements are created. However it doesn't.

I seem to be failing to understand exactly in what scope should I assign the `.popover` property. I know it works because if I do it on the developer tools console, after all page content has been loaded, it works properly. I just don't know where to call it in my code to begin with.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you are manipulating the DOM inside a controller. You should not do this, as the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) says:

> Do not use controllers to:
>
> Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.

In other words, when you use an Angular controller, you're just delegating the DOM manipulation to Angular through $scope databinding.

If you would like to manipulate the DOM, you should rely on directives. In your case, you can create a phonePopover directive like this:

```
angular
    .module('phone', [])
    .directive('phonePopover', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: false,
            scope: {
                phoneText: '=phonePopover'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                element.popover({
                    'trigger': 'hover',
                    'placement': 'right',
                    'content': scope.phoneText
                });
            }
    });
```

And apply it to your element as following:

```
<img data-phone-popover="{{phone.text}}" class="img-responsive phone_image" ng-src="{{phone.image_path}}">
```